# Is there a way to add a password system to a Google Slides document?

Tags: google-slides, passwords

I am currently working on a Google Slides project for my students that would involve them going on a multiple slides, of which there would be a question, and multiple answers.

I currently have the questions and answers put in, and the correct answers will be hyperlinked to slides in which there is a specific number.

These numbers would form a password, of which the password would hopefully be used to enter a specific slide that would show a student won.

I am wondering if there is a way to only let a student into a slide if they knew the correct password, and not just skip past it.
These slides would be assigned to each student indivually.

Comment: This question is unclear and  difficult to follow. Use the language of the app and anchor information precisely to make it easier to follow.  Google Slides app files are `presentations` (or documents) containing `slides` iIf there's only one doc, state that clearly: I have a single `presentation`.  Number the slides in your explanation. For example, Slides 1-10 each... You might want to make a minimal sample presentation and share a link.

Comment: Google Slides is for presentations. Sounds like you are making a quiz.  You might use a Quiz App instead, or leverage Google forms which can return different sections based on  responses.